# How to handle transactions without any framework in java (JDBC)?

Tags: java, jdbc, service, transactions

I am very new to java. I am learning JDBC with simple JSP/Servlet and Service/Dao architecture. Please consider below given code snap.

```
package com.login.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HelloService helloService = new HelloService();
        helloService.doMyUnitOfWork();
    }

}

class HelloService {
    public void doMyUnitOfWork() {
        HelloDao helloDao = new HelloDao();
        // I want to execute all below three works in single unit, it means I want to use single transaction for all database operations.
        // Thus any of my below database operation fails I want to rollback all of them, otherwise commit all in database.
        helloDao.doMyWork1();
        helloDao.doMyWork2();
        helloDao.doMyWork3();
    }
}

class HelloDao {
    public void doMyWork1() {
        // this will do database operation 1.
    }

    public void doMyWork2() {
        // this will do database operation 2.
    }

    public void doMyWork3() {
        // this will do database operation 3.
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in above code snap, I need to handle transaction at service layer with simple JDBC. When I try to Google it, I am getting almost Spring and EJB results rather than simple JDBC.

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the official tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Mkyong makes good tutorials too, just check if it's outdated: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I have already gone through both links you have provided. It seems they have used one transaction for same method. In my case, I need it for different methods and also from different class.

Comment: In that case taking a look into Java Transaction API (JTA) may be helpful, since it's a more advanced requirement. You may also roll your own implementation by sharing JDBC connections across classes, methots and committing at once, but it will quickly become something like an inferior implementation of things such as JTA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Frameworks like Hibernate are using jdbc internally.

You can start transaction with

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

You can rollback your transaction:

```
connection.rollback();
```

And if you want to persist your data in database you call:

```
connection.commit();
```

Your transaction can be closed by using:

```
connection.close();
```

Here is example :

```
Connection connection = ...
try{
connection.setAutoCommit(false);


Statement statement1 = null;
try{
    statement1 = connection.createStatement();
    statement1.executeUpdate(
        "update people set name='John' where id=123");
} finally {
    if(statement1 != null) {
        statement1.close();
    }
}


Statement statement2 = null;
try{
    statement2 = connection.createStatement();
    statement2.executeUpdate(
        "update people set name='Gary' where id=456");
} finally {
    if(statement2 != null) {
        statement2.close();
    }
}

connection.commit();


} catch(Exception e) {
connection.rollback();
}finally {
if(connection != null) {
    connection.close();
}
}
```

Copied from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/transaction.html in case it would be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your time but, It is not what I am looking for. Please see carefully question before you answer.